# Who killed Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

On my Windows machines, it happens that suddenly explorer.exe crashes or gets killed. The task bar and start menu disappear, and all File Explorer windows are closed.

Sometimes, explorer.exe gets restarted immediately, but sometimes not.

I would like to know whether these are crashes or deliberate killings of the explorer.exe process (for example to install Shell plugins, like Dropbox). If it's deliberate, then I'd like to know which process kills Explorer.

In the Event Viewer I can find some errors and warnings (who doesn't?), but nothing specific about explorer.exe at the time of the crash.

**EDIT:** To be precise, this does not happen often. It's about once or twice per month. Since there is no "Windows Explorer ran into a problem" dialogue, I suspect it's not a crash, but a deliberate killing. My most plausible suspect is Dropbox. Maybe they install an update, and to make the update work without restarting the computer, they just shoot down explorer.exe and restart it.

**EDIT 2:** Another suspect is Adobe Creative Suite or Adobe XD. I just had an update of XD installed, and during the installation, explorer.exe disappeared and came back when the installation was finished.

**EDIT 3:** Just observed an Explorer restart right after I logged on to my machine. In the Event Viewer, I see that RestartManager has restarted Explorer, but it does not indicate the reason. But right before it is restarted, I can see events of `gupdate` and `dbupdate` (without any text). This could indicate that either the Google Chrome updater or the Dropbox updater might be the culprit.

**EDIT 4:** I can confirm the first culprit: During the update of Adobe XD, Explorer was restarted by `RestartManager`, as documented in Event Viewer.

Comment: Do you download torrent's?

Comment: @Cris I have a machine where I sometimes do, but this has happened on a machine where I'm 100% certain I have never installed anything torrent-related.

Comment: Scanned for malware lately?

Comment: @Moab: yes, with Windows Defender. "Realtime protection" is turned on.

Comment: Windows 10?....

Comment: @Moab yes, latest version.

Comment: Checked for and installed the latest drivers? What about the various Windows 10 self repair options using DISM?

Comment: @music2myear latest drivers, yes. No, I didn't do any self repair. I have the problem on all my three machines, which otherwise run fine.